# Почему нет соединения БД с datagridview на пользовательском элементе управления?

Tags: datagrid, c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Добавил БД в "Источники данных". Добавил DataGridView в пользовательский элемент управления (назовем его просто - панель), на этом элементе еще есть пара кнопок и меток. Панель будет появляется на форме после нажатия на кнопку на форме и скрываться после нажатия на другую кнопку.

В чем проблема: Добавил в качестве источника данных в DataGridView свою таблицу из БД и при компиляции показывается лишь пустая строка с заголовками. Если же добавить DataGridView на форму, то таблица с данными загружается.

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема, раз заголовки таблицы загружаются, значит доступ к БД есть, но куда данные таблицы деваются?

*Обновление*

Пишу в Visual Studio 2013 Express на C#. 
На msdn нашел такую статью: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171926.aspx

Она не совсем подходит, так как панель я буду вызывать из класса формы, а в статье подразумевается что я добавлю её на форму через конструктор из источника данных.

Но я все равно для проверки попытался сделать. Результат тот же, заголовки есть, но данных нет.

Вот ссылка с проектом: https://www.dropbox.com/s/znfo0kmdnhl3w9v/TestMSSQL.7z

Comment: Ваш элемент не прозрачен, так что внутренний грид не видит внешней таблицы.

Comment: И как его прозрачным сделать?

Comment: Об этом, скорее всего, рассказано в документации к вашей среде программирования.

Comment: Ваш элемент представляет гриду тот набор, который говорит ему использовать?

Comment: Грид использует данные из источника данных, который доступен для всего проекта

Comment: Вашему элементу источник доступен, не сомневаюсь.

Comment: Я тоже в этом не сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

У форм и пользовательских элементов есть событие `Load`, которое происходит при каждой загрузке формы. В общем, нужно реагировать на это событие:

```
private void MyPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.elementsTableAdapter.Fill(this.eSDC_DataBaseDataSet.Elements); 
}
```

В принципе работает, но если изменить таблицу в БД (добавить поле и т.д.), то приходиться заново создавать источник данных. И еще в бд из приложения ничего не записывается =(